# VideoDisplay, using a relative path to local video

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a flex AIR (for desktop) app, it contains a `VideoDisplay`:

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="video" autoPlay="true" source="video/collection1/1.mp4" />
```

Notice how the source property points to a local video in a relative path.

The problem is that the video does not play, except when I use a full path to the video. I have also tried various other paths, such as "./video/etc", "/video/etc" but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strah right. Sometimes problem with `forward and backward slash` for this resolvePath help out based on platform.

```
var filePath:String = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("video/collection1/1.mp4").nativePath;
```

(or)

```
var filePath:String = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("video/collection1/1.mp4").url;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better for platform specific deployment.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var pathToVideo:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "/video/collection1/1.mp4";
```